# When were the baskets invented in Australia and America?

Tags: technology, inventions

Since the human migration to Australia and America took place way before the invention of the baskets and both the pre-colonized Aborigens and Native Americans were using baskets, that means they invented the technology on their own.

And then the question is: when did they invent it?

Answer (score 2):

According to *The Art of Native American Basketry: A Living Legacy* by *Frank Porter*, Native American basketry began between 7000 BC and 5000 BC:

> The beginning of this craft occurred between the years 5000 and 7000 B.C. That seed and nut gatherers of the Great Basin started basketry is evidenced at Hogup Cave, Utah, where 160 fragments of baskets were found, some of them rigid pieces of twining (Adavasio 1970, 183).